# how to realize when getting sendPhoto information (by bot Telegram) ,Which channel has been sent from?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

My bot is registered in several groups and receives data from them.
when receive the the json code.

```
{
    "update_id": 753984481,
    "message": {
        "message_id": 158011,
        "from": {
            "id": 212105015,
            "first_name": "\u0634\u0631\u06a9\u062a \u0635\u0628\u0627 \u0645\u0647\u0631 \u0633\u06cc\u0631\u0627\u0641"
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": -196924840,
            "title": "\u067e\u0631 \u067e\u0631\u0648\u0627\u0632 \u0635\u0628\u0627 \u0645\u0647\u0631 \u0633\u06cc\u0631\u0627\u0641",
            "type": "group",
            "all_members_are_administrators": true
        },
        "date": 1500091212,
        "photo": [
            {
                "file_id": "AgADBAAD9qkxG98UMFNewex76YKoYAr-vBkABEvcu9cjuXx1WCQDAAEC",
                "file_size": 1168,
                "width": 67,
                "height": 90
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I know which message is sent from (Groups)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see, in your json message.chat.type is equal to "group", when your bot receives a message from a channel, its type value will be equal to "channel".

other difference between channels and groups is that the message.chat.id of channels are bigger (13 digit numbers)